# How do you drop a column by index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

When I run this code it drops the first row instead of the first column:

```
df.drop(axis=1, index=0)
```

How do you drop a column by index?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.columns[i]` to denote the column. Example:

```
df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
[1023.423,12.59595],
[1000,11.63024902],
[975,9.529815674],
[100,-48.20524597]], columns = ['col1', 'col2'])

    col1        col2
0   1023.423    12.595950
1   1000.000    11.630249
2   975.000     9.529816
3   100.000     -48.205246
```

If you do `df.drop(index=0)`, the output is dropping row with index 0

```
    col1    col2
1   1000.0  11.630249
2   975.0   9.529816
3   100.0   -48.205246
```

If you do `df.drop('col1', axis=1)`, the output is dropping column with name 'col1'

```
    col2
0   12.595950
1   11.630249
2   9.529816
3   -48.205246
```

Please remember to use `inplace=True` where necessary